# How to use a variable in find command?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, find, command

I am totally new in bash so sorry if my question is not well formatted or does not make sense :)

I'm trying to do something like that:

```
#..................... previous code where F is defining

filename="$F";
echo "$filename";
find . -name ????? | while read fname; do
    echo "$fname";
done;
```

I want to use my variable $filename in find command (instead of ????), but I don't know how. I add some fixed value there for testing purpose, for example "abc.txt" (which exists and is stored in my variable), it works well, I just don't know how to use variable in find command.

Something like

```
find . -name '$filename.txt' | while read fname;
```

UPDATE: (I have 2 files (.xml and .txt) with the same name in folder)

```
find . -type f -name \*.xml | while read F; 
    do something || echo $F;
    cat "$F";
    #name without extenssion
    filename="${F%.*}";
    echo "$filename";
    find . -name "$filename.txt" | while read fname; do
        echo "$fname";
    done;
done;
```

Comment: `find . -name "$filename.txt" ` should work with variables in double quotes.

Comment: @anubhava is correct, you must use double quotes for variables to expand.

Comment: What is the value of `$F` and what is the name of the file you are looking for?

Comment: I think there is problem somewhere else, I don't know this language, I just need to execute few commands, my code looks something like this -> I've put code to UPDATE in my question to be formatted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work:

```
filename="$F";
echo "$filename";
find . -name "$filename.txt" | while read fname; do
    echo "$fname";
done;
```

Although you could just as easily do:

```
find . -name "$F.txt" | while read fname; do
    echo "$fname";
done;
```

Double quotes (or no quotes at all) are necessary for variable expansion. Single quotes will not work.

Comment: you only need the double quotes to help it safely expand (in case there are spaces etc.), the variables will expand without quotes as well--just not within single quotes

Comment: You also need double quotes if use variable with '*'. find . -name "${DB_NAME}*_some_text_*.sh"      find does not work with single quotes and does not return error.